# Validation Errors are Showing Up on Different Record Types / Custom Fields

Tags: validation-rule, record-type

In Salesforce, why would a validation show up on a completely different custom field that is used in a different record type and page layout? Everything has been cleanly separated. The only solution I can come up with is to inactivate the validation formulas that are on the other record type.

For example, I have two record types with their own page layouts. One record type has validations on fields that are not related through any kind of master-detail relationship or lookup field. These are not on any of record type 2's fields.

I inactivated the validations for the record type and they're not showing up on record type 2. Does anyone have a clue as to how this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Validation rule runs on the object level, not on recordType. If you want to run validation rule for only one record type see below example

```
AND(
$RecordType.DeveloperName = 'your_record_Type,
... other conditions
)
```

Comment: Use developer name you can use name but it may change upon business request but developer name will remain same even if you change the label

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you include the recordtype on your validation rule so it only triggers on that specific record type?

```
Recordtypeid = 'rectypeid here' && <actual validation here>
```

Comment: Use correct syntax or psudo code when replying

Comment: That's a correct syntax. What are you talking about? All he needs to do is substitute the values.